Complete Concurrency check enabled and how to resolve warnings
I am looking to resolve the concurrency warnings that I am getting after enabling the complete concurrency check in Xcode.
Here is a simple example to illustrate the warning. Consider I have a  ContentView that has a long running task on the background thread. When I call the long running task inside that of a Task {...} I get a "Passing argument of non-sendable type 'ContentView' outside of main actor-isolated context may introduce data races" warning. I get this warning when I enable the concurrency settings to complete in Xcode.
I tried the suggestion to make the ContentView Sendable but it generates additional warnings(see second image below) and will not work in my situation.
How do I get around this? appreciate any help/direction
See code below:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var disable: Bool = false
    @State private var value: Double = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                disable = true
            } label: {
                Text("Press")
            }
            .task {
                await value = self.fetchValue() //<---Here is the warning. See image below
            }
            Text("\(value)")

        }
    }
}

extension ContentView {
    
    func fetchValue() async -> Double {
        //long running task
        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 60)
        return 2.0
    }
}

Here is the warning:



In order to make this a better question, it would be helpful to shrink your code to the list code needed to show the whole problem. As written, it doesn't compile since it relies on several types you don't provide. You can provide simplified versions of those, and I believe it will be easier for us to help you.

thanks for the feedback, updated the question with the focus area and also the full code to compile and run.

there is no valid reason for mixing Observable and ObservableObject. Observable replaces ObservableObject.

Move the code inside the Task to a task(id: selectedFile)

@loremipsum, May be I am missing something... moving the code into task(id: selectedFile) did not change anything! I still have the same warning. The warning is shown when the concurrency settings is set to complete in Xcode.

@JoakimDanielson, making the fetchValue() static solved one problem but introduced other issues. I am getting the warnings shown in the second image above. Loremipsum's solution works

static in Swift6 will only work with Sendable types. SwiftUI property wrappers are not Sendable so Views will never be Sendable. IMO the whole static thing  will rock a ton of developer's code in the near future. All those singletons will finally be addressed! lol. Though people will likely just mark them with MainActor clogging the thread.

Fundamentally, the issue is that because ContentView is not isolated to any particular actor, fetchValue is nonisolated, too. And nonisolated async functions run on a generic executor (see SE-0338). Isolating ContentView to the main actor is one way to solve that problem. (And in answer to your question, “I thought the view is always on the main thread”, yes, it is, but being “on the main thread” is technically not quite the same thing as being isolated to the main actor.)

A SwiftUI View is not attached to an actor the body is decorated with @MainActor but not the View itself.
When you have func in the View you can decorate the View with @MainActor the same way you would a "ViewModel".
import SwiftUI
@MainActor // Decorate the View
struct AsyncTest: View {
    @State private var isRunning: Bool = false
    @State private var value: Double = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                print("press")
                isRunning = true
            } label: {
                Text("Press")
            }.disabled(isRunning)
                .task(id: isRunning) {
                    guard isRunning else {return}
                    print("start")
                    value = await fetchValue()
                    print("end")
                    isRunning = false
                }
            if isRunning {
                ProgressView()
            }
            
            Text("\(value)")

        }
    }
}

extension AsyncTest {
    
    func fetchValue() async -> Double {
        await Task.detached(priority: .userInitiated) {
            // Mock long runing task
            _ = (0...10000000).map { n in
                n.description
            }.sorted(using: KeyPathComparator(\.description))
            //long running task
            //try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 60)
            return 2.0
        }.value
    }
}
#Preview {
    AsyncTest()
}


this works!! Thank you. I am trying to understand, I thought the view is always on the main thread and why do we need to decorate it with @MainActor?

@RXP People say that but it isn't, only the body is decorated. The View will run on the MainActor by inheritance (root starts on the MA). It just isn't a given you do have the ability to call it in the background.

@RXP Note the "closures" like what you had in the original code don't get locked in by the new Concurrency you still have to move the Task code to .task

got it.. I think I need to move the code into .task because, now it is taking way more time to read the file and using up a ton of memory. Earlier, it used to take about 40 secs to read a file and to read the same file now it is taking more than 10 mins and a ton of memory. I had to kill it... I need to continue researching this...

Yup there are a ton of ways to properly “detach” from the main thread the only thing that should be there is the final assignment.

if I have to use a .fileImporter(...) how do I use it within a .task()? is there a different pattern? I have .fileImporter(..) and within that I have the Task {...}

@RXP use the selectedFile as the id. Look at the isRunning variable. Follow the same pattern.

@RXP you can see this other sample too. It is the same premise https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77080477/how-to-run-async-function-urlsession-inside-a-publisher-onreceive/77080563#77080563

thanks @loremipsum. that helps! I moved the code to .task(id: selectedFile) as you suggested but now it is taking for ever to run and using more than 1 GB of memory. Earlier it was using just 30 mb of memory and finish reading the same file in under 40 secs. Any pointers for me to dig through the issue?

@Rob, that makes sense... let me take that out and put it in a separate app and post it as a new question. Thank you

@RXP was the selected file the url or the file contents? It should be the url to minimize footprint.

the selected file is the url

After looking through a little more, realized that using .task(), the code is running on the main thread. However, the UI is responsive which explains the async/await concept. Is that the reason it is taking a long time? I am trying to isolate the code and replicate the behavior in a separate function but it is a bit hard :-)

@RXP very probable (that is what I think the issue is), like I said above there are a few different ways to safely detach from the main actor something like “someValue = await Task.detached {/* some code */}.value” in the func could work that way only the final assignment is done on the MainActor. It is hard to provide a realistic solution without the full example Rob mentioned.

@RXP this is old but somewhat relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73538764/trouble-running-async-functions-in-background-threads-concurrency/73542522#73542522

@loremipsum, thank you! very interesting. I am realizing how much I don't know and how much I misunderstood the concepts. Let me read through and see how to apply.

@RXP look at the new fetchValue I made a minor change which should resolve your issue.

@loremipsum, posted new question with the fileImporter: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78286044/1219836

@RXP did you try the detached line I added?

@loremipsum yes, I just did and it does not seem to change things!

@loremipsum, Joakim suggested to try running Instruments and very strangely, it takes just under 40 seconds and I tried to run it on the real device and it takes under 40 seconds for reading the same file as well. The problem seems to be happening only in the debug mode which is very strange! Anything I should be doing to speed up in the debug mode?

@RXP I haven't had time to look at your other code. So I am not sure. By DEBUG do you mean Previews? DEBUG by definition is something you change in the Schema, Devices can have debug projects too. If this is isolated to Previews I would suggest just using a smaller file for mocking.

@loremipsum, by Debug, I mean running running in the simulator and real device with debug symbols on - not optimized code. Running the app using instruments, it executes very fast. I am assuming that Instruments would optimize the code. I may be wrong

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@RXP that does seem strange are you sure the body isnt being redrawn?  https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/debugging-swiftui-views/ try using “print changes”

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var disable: Bool = false
    @State private var value: Double = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                disable = true
                fetchAndUpdateValue()
            }) {
                Text("Press")
            }
            Text("\(value)")
        }
    }
    
    private func fetchAndUpdateValue() {
        Task {
            let fetchedValue = await fetchValue()
            value = fetchedValue
        }
    }
}

extension ContentView {
    private func fetchValue() async -> Double {
        // Simulate long running task
        await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 60)
        return 2.0
    }
}

I've created a new private function fetchAndUpdateValue() that performs the async operation and updates the value property accordingly.
When the button is pressed, it sets the disable state and invokes fetchAndUpdateValue() to fetch the value asynchronously.
The fetchValue() function remains unchanged, still performing the async operation.

It's because you have the order of await and value muddled up, try this:
.task {
    value = await AsyncController().fetchValue()
}

Also it's best to change extension AsyncTest to struct AsyncController or something, that way it is not run on the main thread which is what happens to any async func declared inside the View once you use @StateObject or @ObservedObject. What matters is where the func is declared.
struct AsyncController {
    
    func fetchValue() async -> Double {
        //long running task
        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 60)
  
        // safe to do processing here because this will be a background thread

        return 2.0
    }
}


Even better, make the AsyncController an EnvironmentKey so you can mock it for Previews via .environment.
