SwiftUI: How to trigger the onSubmit modifier?
They decimalPad keyboard does not have a return button. So I like to include one using the keyboard toolbar. But how can you create a Submit Button?
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("0", text: $text)
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            .onSubmit {
                // do something
            }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                Button("Submit Button") {
                    // trigger textfield onSubmit() manually
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78282542/complete-concurrency-check-enabled-and-how-to-resolve-warnings/78284318#78284318

@loremipsum wrong link?  That's a concurrency question.  Or is it buried in there somewhere?

I couldn't find the answer neither.

Look at the code, you can use task(id:). It can be triggered from anywhere.

So how does task(id:) help to trigger onSubmit?

It is a different approach. task takes the place of onSubmit

As lorem ipsum said, why do you need to trigger onSubmit specifically? What's wrong with just putting the code you want executed in the submit button's action?

the problem is that the keyboard does not dismiss when you do that. Try my code with and without the endEditing to see Apple stupidity.

You could try something simple like this (for iOS devices), using ....endEditing(true):
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("0", text: $text).border(.red)
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                    Button("Submit Button") {
                        print("do something")
                        let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
                        windowScene?.windows.first?.endEditing(true)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}


This will dismiss the keyboard, which could also be achieved by SwiftUI native focused(:). Unfortunately it won't trigger the onSubmit.

I found a thorough article on the same matter: https://christiantietze.de/posts/2023/06/swiftui-onsubmit/ he also reached a deadend.

the print("do something") in the ToolbarItem Button, is meant to be what you would do in the .onSubmit{...}, since .onSubmit{...} is just a place where you do something.
