Update Text with progress from worker
I'm very new to Swift and struggling with have a Text field update based on the progress of a async worker function.
I've searched and played around for hours on this but not there. This post seems to be the right idea but I can't get it to work in my example.  Any suggestions?
public class ExportEngine : ObservableObject
{
    @Published var curFileIdx : Int
    @Published var isRunning : Bool
    
    init?()
    { 
        self.curFileIdx = 0
        self.isRunning = false
    }
    
    @MainActor
    public func exportFiles() async
    {
        isRunning = true;
        
        for i in (0...10)
        {
            curFileIdx = i
            print("i = \(i)")
            sleep(5)
        }
        isRunning = false
    }
}

struct ContentView: View
{
    @ObservedObject var reloadViewHelper = ReloadViewHelper()
    @ObservedObject var exportEngine : ExportEngine

    @State private var pctComplete = 0.0
        
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            Button("Run")
            {
                print("run")
                // do what here?
            }
            
            Text("File \(exportEngine.curFileIdx)") // doesn't like this
            .refreshable
            {
                Task
                {
                    await exportEngine.exportFiles()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

EDIT I
The accepted answer from @Hollycene works but if the export file process takes a long time, the UI freezes until it completes.
I tried having the ExportEngine class without @MainActor but have only one method within it as @MainActor to update the UI.
In that case got the error Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.
What does that mean?
Like this:
public class ExportEngine : ObservableObject {
@Published var curFileIdx : Int = 0

@MainActor
private func updateUI(idx: Int)
{
    curFileIdx = idx
}

public func exportFiles() async
{
    for i in (0...10) {
        updateUI(idx: i)
        print("i = \(i)")
        
        // it waits 1 second before the next iteration
        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
    }
}

}

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77080477/how-to-run-async-function-urlsession-inside-a-publisher-onreceive/77080563#77080563 also, don’t use “sleep” use “Task.sleep”

This is a simple solution for updating a Text view from an async function triggered by a button, as in your example.
However, you need to consider multiple scenarios when working with concurrency, such as canceling unfinished tasks when the user leaves the screen or when they tap the button again before the current task finishes.
It all depends on your use case and the logic of your app.
import SwiftUI

public class ExportEngine : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var curFileIdx : Int = 0
    @Published var isRunning : Bool = false

    @MainActor
    public func exportFiles() async
    {
        isRunning = true
        
        for i in (0...10) {
            curFileIdx = i
            print("i = \(i)")
            
            // it waits 1 second before the next iteration
            try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
        }
        
        isRunning = false
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    // Initialize the exportEngine here as the @StateObject or pass the reference from the parent view as the @ObservedObject
    @StateObject private var exportEngine = ExportEngine()
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Run") {
                // This task handles the execution of your async function.
                // However, you need to handle the cancelation of this task in certain situations
                // (for example cancel the task when the use leaves the screen, etc.)
                Task {
                    await exportEngine.exportFiles()
                }
            }
            
            // Progress view is visible only when the engine is running
            if exportEngine.isRunning {
                ProgressView()
            }
            
            Text("File \(exportEngine.curFileIdx)")
        }
    }
}


#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


EDIT 1
I took a look at the issue mentioned in "Edit 1" of the question, but I wasn't able to replicate the UI freezing or the Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed error.
However, I made some adjustments to the provided solution by applying @MainActor only to the methods that specifically update UI-related properties. This approach works in my case. Are you still encountering the issue? Or is the problem you mentioned occurring in your specific app scenario?
tested on iOS 17.5, Swift 5
import SwiftUI

public class ExportEngine : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var curFileIdx : Int = 0
    @Published var isRunning : Bool = false

    // --> Use @MainActor only on the functions directly updating UI-related properties
    @MainActor
    private func updateCurFile(idx: Int)
    {
        curFileIdx = idx
    }
    
    @MainActor
    private func updateIsRunning(value: Bool)
    {
        isRunning = value
    }

    // --> Do not use @MainActor on other methods not related to the UI
    public func exportFiles() async
    {
        await updateIsRunning(value: true)
        
        for i in (0...10) {
            await updateCurFile(idx: i)
            print("i = \(i)")
            
            // it waits 1 second before the next iteration
            try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
        }
        
        await updateIsRunning(value: false)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    // Initialize the exportEngine here as the @StateObject or pass the reference from the parent view as the @ObservedObject
    @StateObject private var exportEngine = ExportEngine()
        
    var body: some View {
        // --> I added the ScrollView to try the UI responsivity during the execution of `exportFiles()` method,
        // in order to demonstrate that the UI is responsive and not blocked by the execution.
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Button("Run") {
                    // This task handles the execution of your async function.
                    // However, you need to handle the cancelation of this task in certain situations
                    // (for example cancel the task when the use leaves the screen, etc.)
                    Task {
                        await exportEngine.exportFiles()
                    }
                }
                
                // Progress view is visible only when the engine is running
                if exportEngine.isRunning {
                    ProgressView()
                }
                
                Text("File \(exportEngine.curFileIdx)")
            }
            .padding(.top, 100)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
    }
}


#Preview {
    ContentView()
}



If you use .task instead of Task you dont need the StateObject

Yeah, good point, malhal! I use the @StateObject in my answer because the ExportEngine class is provided in the answer, so I wanted to keep the reference to the original answer.

@malhal, can you explain what you mean or give an example?  I'm a C++ guy who's been programming in swift for only 10 days now.  Steep learning curve.

@Hollycene, this is working well but if the "export" function takes a long time the UI is not updated. I guess because it is running in the @MainActor ?  But removing @MainActor gives me Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.. See updated question above

@Danny, I updated my answer, however I wasn't able to replicate your issue in my use case. Are you still getting the error? Is the error occurring in your specific app use case?

As @lorem ipsum said, you should switch to Task.sleep, since sleep will suspend thread execution, which is the Main thread.
print("i = \(i)")
try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(5) //<- here

Additionally, you tie Text to curFileIdx, so that every time curFileIdx changes, it will also update the Text. You have done this in exportFiles().
curFileIdx = i

I assume this action should be executed when tapping on Run button.
VStack {
    Button("Run") {
        Task {
            await exportEngine.exportFiles() //<- here
        }
    }
    if exportEngine.isRunning { //<- I added a progress view here to represent running state
        ProgressView()
    }
    Text("File \(exportEngine.curFileIdx)")
}

This is the output:


However, there is an issue here. @MainActor was added to your exportFiles(). As a result, it always runs the entire process on the Main thread. On the other hand, all that's needed to appear on Text is curFileIdx. Therefore, it's better to do other stuffs on different threads and only access Main thread when necessary.
@MainActor //<- here
public class ExportEngine: ObservableObject {
     ...

     nonisolated //<- here
     public func exportFiles() async {
         for i in (0...5) {
            await MainActor.run {
                print("get \(i) on thread: \(Thread.current)")
                curFileIdx = i
            }
            print("running \(i) on thread: \(Thread.current)")
            try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
        }
     }
}

get 0 on thread: <_NSMainThread: 0x6000017040c0>{number = 1, name = main}
running 0 on thread: <NSThread: 0x6000017021c0>{number = 3, name = (null)}
get 1 on thread: <_NSMainThread: 0x6000017040c0>{number = 1, name = main}
running 1 on thread: <NSThread: 0x6000017021c0>{number = 3, name = (null)}
get 2 on thread: <_NSMainThread: 0x6000017040c0>{number = 1, name = main}
running 2 on thread: <NSThread: 0x60000174c980>{number = 7, name = (null)}
get 3 on thread: <_NSMainThread: 0x6000017040c0>{number = 1, name = main}
running 3 on thread: <NSThread: 0x600001754480>{number = 4, name = (null)}
get 4 on thread: <_NSMainThread: 0x6000017040c0>{number = 1, name = main}
running 4 on thread: <NSThread: 0x600001754480>{number = 4, name = (null)}
get 5 on thread: <_NSMainThread: 0x6000017040c0>{number = 1, name = main}
running 5 on thread: <NSThread: 0x600001754480>{number = 4, name = (null)}


What a coincidence, I added the answer at the same time as you and
also provided the ProgressView to demonstrate the "loading" state. Anyway, good point with the @MainActor! I would only add (as I mentioned in my answer) that it is important to consider different scenarios and cancel the unfinished task appropriately.

Haha holy moly, I didn't notice that xD.
